# i need to know which command i can use for this vbscript

Tags: vbscript, notepad

I'm making a "test program" in notepad using vbscript. My first command is "type in name" and i want to say welcome and then the name that they've typed. any suggestions?

this is the code:

```
  Dim speaks, speech
    speaks="Welcome" 
    Set speech=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice") 
    speech.Speak speaks
    Dim msg, sapi 
    msg=InputBox("Type your name in the box below and press ENTER to      proceed","Notepad","YOUR NAME HERE") 
    Set sapi=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice") 
    sapi.Speak msg
    speaks="This is my test program" 
    Set speech=CreateObject("sapi.spvoice") 
    speech.Speak speaks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to keep creating instances of `sapi.spvoice`. Just create it once and reuse it. You can also combine all of your strings into one, which is what it sounds like you're trying to do.

```
Set speech = CreateObject("sapi.spvoice")

msg = InputBox("Type your name in the box below and press ENTER to proceed", "Notepad", "YOUR NAME HERE")

speech.Speak "Welcome " & msg & ". This is my program."
```